"Higher" dimension version of Cauchy–Schwarz inequality?
Assume $F$ is a function on $[n]$ such that $0\le F(x)\le 1$ for every $1\le x\le n$. Let $\sigma_i:[n]\rightarrow [n]$ be an arbitrary bijection for each $i\ge 1$. And let $F_i(x)=F(\sigma_i(x))$ for each $x$.
Then by Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, $\sum_{x\in [n]}F_1(x)F_2(x)\le \sum_{x\in [n]}F^2(x)$.
I am wondering is it true that  $$\sum_{x\in [n]}\prod_{i=1}^kF_i(x)\le \sum_{x\in [n]}F^k(x)$$
for every $k\ge 2$?

Yes, it's true, but it doesn't seem to follow by an induction argument with the usual Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
It follows from the Holder inequality for multiple functions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality?wprov=sfla1), which is an easy consequence of the usual Holder inequality.
In alternative, it's a trivial consequence of the generalized rearrangement inequality, which is not easy to prove: Rearrangement inequality for multiple sequences..
